# Unable do debug JavaScript file due to insufficient permission in VS code in Linux

Tags: javascript, linux, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm not being able to debug JavaScript file in Visual Studio Code. When I press run and debug button in the sidebar. I got following error message.

> Unable to create 'launch.json' file inside the '.vscode' folder (Unable to write file '/var/www/.vscode/launch.json' (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/.vscode')).

and then I tried changing the permission of /var/www folder by using following command:

> **sudo chmod +w /var/www/**

I checked whether the permission to write was added or not by using:

> root@comp[/var/www/]# ls -lah | grep www

Then I got following result:

> drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  4.0K Apr 30 10:35 www

It means the permission to write inside the folder was granted.
Then I again tried by clicking run and debug button in vs code. It sent me same error, even after changing the permission.

I also tried:

> chmod +x -r /var/www/

It didn't work.

What can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: Try chown to your own account.

Comment: @kometen what is the syntax, suppose if the username is ram?

Comment: I advise you to take some time to become acquainted with basic UNIX-commands. https://fossbytes.com/basic-linux-commands-beginners/

Comment: I did chown username:username /var/www/ and it worked!!